# Reparent a view in Android - move from one layout to another

Tags: android

I'm coming from iOS where I can simply reparent a view under another view.  I'm trying to figure out the equiv in Android.  I want to move an imageview up a couple of spots in the view hierarchy when clicked.  Something like:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    //Tile touchBegan
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)(getParent().getParent());
        rl.addView(this);
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of course.. but just trying to figure out how to re-parent a view under another layout.  I found this example searching around which seems incredibly complicated..

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If I remember my old iOS experience right it removes the view from it's old parent automatically if you add it to another one (I might be wrong ;-).

Here's how you would do the same on android:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) yourChildView.getParent();     

if (parent != null) {
    // detach the child from parent or you get an exception if you try
    // to add it to another one
    parent.removeView(yourChildView);
}

// you might have to update the layout parameters on your child
// for example if your child was attached to a RelativeLayout before
// and you add it to a LinearLayout now
// this seems very odd coming from iOS but iOS doesn't support layout
// management, so...
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutP...
yourChildView.setLayoutParams(params);

yourNewParent.addView(yourChildView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,  This is working for me now!  Seems too easy, I thought I had tried this.  I think I was casting the parent to my layout type of RelativeLayout.. maybe that was causing my issue.

Answer (score 9):

```
((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
newContainer.addView(view)
```