# Draggable Expandablelistview parent and child relationship Android

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview, draggable

I have implement Expandable list view in navigation drawer.
My Question is I have drag and drop Work to Personal so now Work is personal child this is possible in android?

That is possible how?

```
Project
 -Personal
 -Work
 -Shopping
```

Now i do this like work is personal child how to add using draggable is this possible?

```
 Project
  -Personal
    -Work
  -Shopping
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout. My be you'll get reference idea.

Comment: Yes right but in my Questions add parent to child please see above example@BhoomikaPatel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699275/reparent-a-view-in-android-move-from-one-layout-to-another/7700542